# dynamically transform data into dataframe - Rstudio

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm working on a personal project in R, and I need to dynamically transform my data into data.frame type. Firstly, I download the data from yahoo finance and get prices for 5 different stocks: AAPL, MSFT, FB, AMZN, DELL.

The data is stored in tables and I use the stock names to differentiate all the tables.
I would like to get some advice on how to transform each of my tables into data.frames without having to call each one of them, like:

```
AAPL <- as.data.frame(APPL)
```

I've tried building a custom function, using for loops but nothing seems to work for me. for example:

```
con_data_frame <- function(table) {

 table <- as.data.frame(table)
 return()

}
```

I do not know if my approach is correct. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the data in a list using `mget` and use `lapply` to convert to dataframe.

```
stocks <- c('AAPL', 'MSFT', 'FB', 'AMZN', 'DELL')
list_data <- lapply(mget(stocks), as.data.frame)
```

`list_data` would have a list of dataframes in them. If you want them as separate dataframe use

```
list2env(list_data, .GlobalEnv)
```